# access code origin error

Tags: java, json, access-control

I have a problem when I am calling json from my javascript code. I provide the correct json data (tested it in a browser) but it doesnt work and gives me an access code origin error. What should I do?

A screenshot of the problem I am facing is http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/7889/51046911.png

Thanks,
Kabeer

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

1) Take a look at the SO link I posted above: it should answer your question.

2) This sounds like it might be an issue with JSONP.  There's some good background here:

http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

3) Also: why are you trying to read "count.php" as a Javascript file???

I would think a .php file should contain PHP code, and a .js file should contain Javascript code.  This is the second time in two days I've seen somebody trying to do this - and I really wonder "why???"

IMHO...

Comment: the 'count.php' is analytics provided by the webhost which checks how many hits I am getting